# Телеграмм бот который присылает погоду

Tags: python, бот, telegram

Решил сделать тг бота, который будет брать погоду с сайта и присылать в группу. Написал, но получаю ошибку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону мне копать?

Вот собственно сам код.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pog = 'https://world-weather.ru/pogoda/russia/moscow/'

r = requests.get(pog)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for temp in soup.find_all('div', id = 'weather-now-number'):
    temp = temp.text

for obl in soup.find_all('span', id = 'weather-now-icon'):
    obl = obl.get('title')

for timew in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'weather-now-info'):
    timew = timew.text[6:-3]

for dr in soup.find_all('div', id = 'weather-now-descriprion'):

    line = dr.text
    last_index = 0
    itog = []
    for i, char in enumerate(line[1:-9]):
        if char.istitle() or i == len(line[1:-10]):
               itog.append(line[last_index:i + 1])
               last_index = i + 1
    itog.append(line[-10:-4])
    itog.append(line[-4:])
    dr = ' '.join(itog[:-5])

send_tg = 'Погода в Москве: ' + '\n' + temp + ' ' + obl + '\n' + dr + '\n' + 'Данные на: ' + timew
print(send_tg)
```

Выдаёт следующую ошибку.

```
send_tg = 'Погода в Москве: ' + '\n' + temp + ' ' + obl + '\n' + dr + '\n' + 'Данные на: ' + timew
                                           
NameError: name 'temp' is not defined
```

Comment: Там же только один такой id "current_weather"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы начинающий, по пробуйте взаимодействовать с другим сайтом подобного характера. Данный сайт изначально на 8ой строке блокирует доступ, по этому у вас ничего получается. Рекомендую найти другой сайт, либо обходить защиты сайтов, применять user-agent запросы и.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решение данной проблемы

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pog = 'https://world-weather.ru/pogoda/russia/moscow/'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(pog, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

temp = soup.find('div', id='weather-now-number')

print(temp)

for obl in soup.find_all('span', id = 'weather-now-icon'):
    obl = obl.get('title')

for timew in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'weather-now-info'):
    timew = timew.text[6:-3]

for dr in soup.find_all('div', id = 'weather-now-descriprion'):

    line = dr.text
    last_index = 0
    itog = []
    for i, char in enumerate(line[1:-9]):
        if char.istitle() or i == len(line[1:-10]):
               itog.append(line[last_index:i + 1])
               last_index = i + 1
    itog.append(line[-10:-4])
    itog.append(line[-4:])
    dr = ' '.join(itog[:-5])

send_tg = 'Погода в Москве: ' + '\n' + str(temp) + ' ' + str(obl) + '\n' + str(dr) + '\n' + 'Данные на: ' + str(timew)
print(send_tg)
```

Был добавлен user-agent. В коде много ошибок, например id weather-now-descriprion я не нашел на сайте

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,благодаря ему я начал немного больше разбираться.
Понял что надо было ссылать через str + я так понял мы эмитировали запрос)
И конечно же я перепутал букву в descripTion

Comment: @ADDDoN да, find_all применяется если несколько элементов. 2 и более элементов одного класса уже можно ложить в цикл и взаимодействовать с ними.